# Using vcr to stub ViewPoint gem returns Unauthorize response from ews API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, exchangewebservices, vcr, viewpoint

I am stubbing all requests that go through the [ViewPoint gem](https://github.com/WinRb/Viewpoint). Using the [vcr gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'vcr'

describe CalendarImporters::Ews::Get do
  let(:conf_connection) { FactoryGirl.create(:conf_connection)}
  let(:calendar) { create(:calendar, :for_ews) }
  let(:connection) { Connections::Ews.new(conf_connection, calendar.ews_email) }

  it "works" do
    VCR.use_cassette("a/cassette") do
      connection.client.get_folder(:calendar)
    end
  end
end
```

`connection.client` returns a new `ViewPoint` connection.

The response i get back from the gem is: `Viewpoint::EWS::Errors::UnauthorizedResponseError` which equates to a 401 unauthorised code from the ews api.

I found this issue: https://github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/297

It is exactly the same problem I am having, but it is 3 years old and with no solution. All of my other google foo has turned up nothing.

Digging into the viewpoint gem, I can't find any difference between the request objects apart from: `HTTPClient` and  `WebMockHTTPClient` which is to be expected.

Comment: Do you know any public website with NTLM authentication so it is possible to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak Unfortunately not.

Comment: What about logs on the EWS side?

Comment: @ishe_ua I hadn't thought to look there, I guess it couldn't hurt. We have currently solved this by just stubbing the method call to return what we expect. But it _will_ come up again. I will attempt to dig a little deeper then.

Comment: Does the given cassette exists?

Comment: @obenda there were no cassettes involved here. It was a discrepancy between running a spec with VCR and without VCR.

Answer (score 1):

ViewPoint is using HTTPClient for its connection, so you need to configure VCR to use hook into :webmock and stub your requests.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I anticipate returning to this at some point in the new year. I will let update the question when i find that out.